# Unable to connect to kibana/elasticsearch using docker-compose

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose, connection, kibana

I am trying to run `Kibana` in `Elasticsearch` through a `docker-compose` containarized file (`.yml`) in a virtual machine, but I am unable to connect to `Kibana` and the message that I get while it's unsuccessfully trying to connect is shown below:

```
[34mspark-master     |[0m 18/09/25 17:58:29 INFO master.Master: Registering worker 172.18.0.8:8881 with 2 cores, 1024.0 MB RAM
[36;1mspark-worker     |[0m 18/09/25 17:58:29 INFO worker.Worker: Successfully registered with master spark://spark-master:7077
[35mkibana           |[0m {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-09-25T17:58:31Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://elasticsearch:9200/"}
[35mkibana           |[0m {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-09-25T17:58:31Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"No living connections"}
[35mkibana           |[0m {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-09-25T17:58:33Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://elasticsearch:9200/"}
[35mkibana           |[0m {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-09-25T17:58:33Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"No living connections"}
[35mkibana           |[0m {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-09-25T17:58:36Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://elasticsearch:9200/"}
[35mkibana           |[0m {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-09-25T17:58:36Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"No living connections"}
[35mkibana           |[0m {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-09-25T17:58:38Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://elasticsearch:9200/"}
[35mkibana           |[0m {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-09-25T17:58:38Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":1,"message":"No living connections"}
[35mkibana           |[0m {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-09-25T17:58:41Z","tags":["status","plugin:elasticsearch@6.2.2","info"],"pid":1,"state":"green","message":"Status changed from red to green - Ready","prevState":"red","prevMsg":"Unable to connect to Elasticsearch at http://elasticsearch:9200."}
[33melasticsearch    |[0m 2018-09-25 17:58:47,078 INFO exited: create-index (exit status 0; expected)
```

If you notice, docker is able to connect to other services mentioned in the docker-compose file, one of which is `spark-master` shown in the first 2 lines. The command to call kibana in the docker-compose file is as follows:

```
  elasticsearch:
    build: docker-elasticsearch/
    container_name: elasticsearch
    hostname: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - Des.network.host=0.0.0.0
      - cluster.name = "elasticsearch"
    expose:
      - 9200
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"


  kibana:
    build: kibana/
    container_name: kibana
    hostname: kibana
    environment:
      - SERVER_NAME="kibana"
      - SERVER_HOST="0"
      - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    links:
      - elasticsearch
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
```

If I do `docker-compose ps`, it gives me following:

```
    Name                 Command             State              Ports           
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
elasticsearch   /usr/local/bin/docker-entr   Up       0.0.0.0:9200->9200/tcp,   
                ...                                   9300/tcp                  
kibana          /bin/bash /usr/local/bin/k   Up       0.0.0.0:5601->5601/tcp
```

I searched for this issue extensively on google before posting this question here, and tried various suggestions that people had for this issue that included modifying the `elasticsearch_url`, such as changing `http` to `https`, changing `localhost` to `elasticsearch` and the combination/permutation of these two suggestions, but I was not able to connect to `Kibana` using any of the suggestion. It was also suggested somewhere to check the allocated memory for my virtual machine, which for my VM was equal to the value [suggested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/vm-max-map-count.html) by `Elasticsearch`.

### EDIT-1

On using the commands given by @Ivthillo, it seems Kibana gets connected as shown by the following messages on terminal:

```
kibana_1         | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-09-26T13:43:05Z","tags":["info","monitoring-ui","kibana-monitoring"],"pid":1,"message":"Starting all Kibana monitoring collectors"}
kibana_1         | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-09-26T13:43:06Z","tags":["license","info","xpack"],"pid":1,"message":"Imported license information from Elasticsearch for the [monitoring] cluster: mode: basic | status: active"}
kibana_1         | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2018-09-26T13:43:12Z","tags":["listening","info"],"pid":1,"message":"Server running at http://0:5601"}
```

However, when I try running another service through docker (e.g. `sudo docker exec -i`) in a new terminal (becase the above message `Server is running at...` remains stuck as it does not move ahead), I get an error indicating container is not running as follows:

```
Error response from daemon: Container 824846b64950d7e6f38792c5633f9eca3e84702cfe060de012c4fe39cf365ab9 is not running
```

Comment: So now if you go to http://localhost:5601 can you login into kibana and see that it connects perfectly to your elasticsearch node? What do you mean by " try running another service through docker"? The `docker exec` command **runs a command in a running container**. This container must be running before you run `docker exec` on it, that's why you're seeing this error

Comment: @Lafa: Yes, that link took me to Kibana (`http://localhost:5601/app/kibana#/home?_g=()`) where I can see various tabs for different functionalities, so it seems to be working. I am very new to docker, so I am not sure how to synthesize `image` command with other commands I have in the main docker-compose (`.yml`) file without breaking the compatibility that does not give me errors. The docker-compose file I have contains commands for 4-5 other micro services (spark, hadoop, etc.) that are all in one single file, so I am not sure how changing `build` to `image` would affect everything.

Comment: Ok. So you have multiple **services** in one single docker-compose file, which is the purpose of it, after all. When you choose do build a service with an `image` you're getting a prebuilt one, whereas by going with build, you're usually building one from scratch. You should have a `Dockerfile` inside `docker-elasticsearch/` and `kibana`, am I right? I'd say the issue is with them. You could edit your post with the mentioned files so we can have look

Comment: Yes, I do have `docker` files in those two directories you mentioned.

Comment: So you problem is not your docker-compose file, but your Dockerfile's

Comment: @Lafa: Is it possible to connect to Kibana if I want to use `build` instead of `image` as present in the original docker-compose file? I think the reason to use `build` may be have to do with scalability/cloud issue, although I am not sure how the choice between `build` and `image` would affect that.

Comment: It is definitely possible. I would not be so sure that by opting for image or build would affect anything in terms of performance or scalability. Usually building your own image would have to do with customising the containers as you wish. Then gain, anything I say here without looking at your Dockerfile would be purely speculation...

Comment: @Lafa: Let's assume I want to go with the `build` option, how can I make Kibana to run in that case? As originally shown in the question, I am unable to run Kibana using `build` option... cc: @lvthillo

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180963/discussion-between-lafa-and-user11).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can maybe start from this very basic docker-compose, because you are building your own images which makes this hard to debug.

In the example below we start an ES and a Kibana inside the same docker network which means they can access each other using their name. Networking is a better way to make containers communicated than using deprecated `--link`.

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.3.2
    environment:
      SERVER_NAME: kibana.example.org
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://elasticsearch:9200
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    networks:
      - my-network

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.3.2
    container_name: elasticsearch
    networks:
      - my-network

networks:
  my-network:
```

To prove the connection is working. I'm accessing the kibana container and ping and `curl` to my elasticsearch container:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
7e2632aff839        docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.3.2                 "/usr/local/bin/kiba…"   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        0.0.0.0:5601->5601/tcp   es_kibana_1
03f2d03a87b4        docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.3.2   "/usr/local/bin/dock…"   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        9200/tcp, 9300/tcp       elasticsearch
 lorenzvanthillo@MacBook-Pro  ~/ES  docker exec -it 7e2632aff839 bash
bash-4.2$ ping elasticsearch
PING elasticsearch (172.22.0.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from elasticsearch.es_my-network (172.22.0.2): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.554 ms
64 bytes from elasticsearch.es_my-network (172.22.0.2): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.075 ms
bash-4.2$ curl http://elasticsearch:9200
{
  "name" : "f9AfdJp",
  "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "YQkmS6gtTmqcCs0HgWX5bg",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "6.3.2",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "053779d",
    "build_date" : "2018-07-20T05:20:23.451332Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.3.1",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Comment: Hello @Ivthillo: I tried adding a network as you suggested, where I pick a `my-network` by looking at `sudo docker network ls` and replacing `my-network` in the above lines of code with `bridge`. On running `sudo docker-compose up` I get an error that says `Service elasticsearch uses an undefined network bridge`.

Comment: Even using the name from the identity of the network connection (for e.g. `esp0`) throws that error.

Comment: The compose file will add the network, you don't have to do that manually (don't replace it with bridge which is the default bridge network)

Comment: OK. I just kept that as `my-network` and it didn't give an error, but even then it couldn't connect kibana. I didn't add the `image` like you have shown, instead I have it in `build` form as shown in question; do you think that needs to be changed as well, and if yes, would that impact my setup in any way? Thanks.

Comment: Can you test with the official images?

Comment: It seems like it is able to connect Kibana if I include your provided commands in my bigger docker-compose file that also includes commands for other services, but it won't run kafka/zookeeper when I try using docker to run them in a new terminal. Please see my update in the question regarding the messages I get on terminal.

Comment: docker exec -it is for going inside a running container, to run a container you need to use docker run -d ... (and if you want to connect to the other container it needs to run inside the same docker network: docker run -d --network=my-network ...

Comment: I think if I am able to connect to Kibana without `image` (keeping the format I have originally using `build`) then it may not give the other errors for other services that I just showed. I am not an expert in docker, so it is difficult to synthesize `image` command with other commands I have in the main docker-compose file to avoid breaking the compatibility that does not give me errors. I am willing to use your provided suggestion, but in that case I think the commands for the other 4-5 services mentioned in the docker-compose file may also need to be modified. So, please advise.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar setup. I solved this issue by managing the containers network. Try the following:

```
version: '3'
services:
 elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.6.12
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
    ports:
      - 9200:9200

  kibana:
    image: kibana:5.6.12
    container_name: kibana
    environment:
      ELASTICSEARCH_URL: http://elasticsearch1:9200
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: You're right. I just tried to edit your code with my proposal approach. You can remove the `links` from the kibana setting that it would still connect correctly with your elastic container.

Comment: Actually, you should not even have to deal with networking and linking, since, from the docker-compose doc itself, `by default, any service can reach any other service at that service’s name.`

Comment: True, but it's still more clean to use your own custom networks instead of the generated compose networks. For example when you need to extend your compose with multiple networks.

Comment: Sure @lvthillo. I'm saying this in the context of the problem the user is facing.

Comment: Hello @Lafa: I did not get an error (as commented under @Ivthillo) using the format you presented, but it did not help connect. Nothin changed in terms of the messages on terminal, they are just like I posted in the question.

Comment: Do you have custom images for both ES and Kibana? The only thing I could see here would be some versioning issue. Try using a prebuilt oficial image. I edited my answer with a fully tested file. Give it a try.

Comment: @Lafa: Thanks. Please see the edit under the question on the update after implementing what you and the other user suggested. Basically, I can connect to Kibana using the `image`, but my other services would not run as commented under @Ivthillo's last comment.